# PivotField.AutoShow and Excel 2011 for mac

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to use the [.autoshow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835595.aspx) method in a pivot table but I get a "1004" error message every time. I am trying to us it under Excel 2011 for mac. I am not sure if this method works on my version of Excel, could somebody help?

Here is the procedure I have been working on

```
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1).PivotFields("City").AutoShow Top:=xlAutomatic, Range:=xlTop, _
Count:=6, Field:="Digital channel"
```

The source table looks like this (I shortened it, it actually has 91 rows)

```
+-----------------+-----------------+------------+
|      City       | Digital channel |  Callsign  |
+-----------------+-----------------+------------+
| Baie-Saint-Paul |           13,00 | CIMT-DT-4  |
| Baie-Saint-Paul |           26,00 | CFTF-DT-10 |
| Baie-Saint-Paul |           36,00 | CKRT-DT-1  |
| Baie-Comeau     |            9,00 | CFTF-DT-5  |
| Baie-Trinité    |           12,00 | CIVF-DT    |
| Cabano          |           12,00 | CFTF-DT-3  |
| Cabano          |           21,00 | CKRT-DT-4  |
| Cabano          |           23,00 | CIMT-DT-8  |
| Carleton        |           44,00 | CFTF-DT-11 |
| Carleton        |            5,00 | CHAU-DT    |
| Carleton        |           15,00 | CIVK-DT    |
| Chandler        |           26,00 | CHAU-DT-4  |
| Chapeau         |           23,00 | CIVP-DT    |
| Chicoutimi      |           46,00 | CJPM-DT    |
| Cloridorme      |           11,00 | CHAU-DT-8  |
| Dégelis         |           25,00 | CKRT-DT-2  |
| Forestville     |            4,00 | CFTF-DT-4  |
+-----------------+-----------------+------------+
```

And the pivot table looks like this

```
+-------------------+-----------------+
|       City        | Digital channel |
+-------------------+-----------------+
| Baie-Comeau       |               9 |
| Baie-Saint-Paul   |              75 |
| Baie-Trinité      |              12 |
| Cabano            |              56 |
| Carleton          |              64 |
| Chandler          |              26 |
| Chapeau           |              23 |
| Chicoutimi        |              46 |
| Cloridorme        |              11 |
| Dégelis           |              25 |
| Forestville       |               4 |
| Gascons           |              32 |
| Gaspé             |              71 |
| Gatineau          |             104 |
| Grand-Fonds       |              31 |
| L'Anse-a-Valleau, |              12 |
| Les Escoumins     |              68 |
| Montreal          |             263 |
| Parent            |               0 |
| Percé             |              53 |
| Port-Daniel       |              10 |
| Quebec City       |             113 |
| Radisson          |               0 |
| Rimouski          |             105 |
| Rivière-au-Renard |               4 |
| Rivière-du-Loup   |             110 |
| Roberval          |               0 |
| Rouyn-Noranda     |              50 |
| Saguenay          |              79 |
+-------------------+-----------------+
```

Thank you!

Comment: I recorded a macro in Excel 2011 for Mac and got this code when I choose top 6 for city: `ExecuteExcel4Macro "(""PivotTable1"",TRUE,""City"",6)"`. And it showed top 6 for City by Digital Channel. I suspect the `AutoShow` method is not compatible with VBA for Mac.

Comment: Hi scott Holtzman, I recorded a macro as you did and it did produce a similar code, the weird thing is that when I tried to run the code again, I received a 1004 error message telling me that the formula contained and error.